How can I prevent the access from the User-agents which doesn't have a certain value for ALB
I am using ALB target-group, rule condition.
Currently, I succeeded to prevent the access from Android,

However what I want to do is prevent the access which doesn't include the Android
So this is vice versa.
What is the best practice for this purpose?

This type of thing is better handled by a Web Application Firewall, instead of load balancer rules. https://aws.amazon.com/waf/
